# TypeError: botframework_directlinejs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to integrate latest Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat with my sample react app following:

- `npm install botframework-webchat@master`
- in the constructor:

  ```
  this.directLine = new DirectLine({ token: 'YOUR_BOT_SECRET' });

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactWebChat directLine={ this.directLine } />
       my elements
    );
  }
  ```

These are straight forward steps followed from 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Import Stuff

```
import DirectLine from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat from 'botframework-webchat';
```

directlinejs got from

> npm i botframework-directlinejs

Comment: `console.log(DirectLine)`. `console.log(ReactWebChat)`. Are they functions? Is it importing correctly?

Comment: Please show the full component code. Important stuff is missing to be able to help you.

Comment: @Dez edited question. From the console logs **ReactWebChat** is a function but **DirectLine** was undefined

Answer (score 2):

Got it.
It was imports problem

```
import DirectLine from 'botframework-directlinejs';
```

changed to

```
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
```

works for me.

Comment: You have no idea how much headache this error caused me, thank you for posting the answer.